# Ionic 1.x - from bower to npm

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, bower

I used to install plugins in my ionic 1 project with bower. The new trend, especially with ionic 2, is to install packages with npm. Some core packages, such as [ionic.cloud](http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#installation) are not provided at all anymore with bower, even for ionic 1.x.

So I need to migrate some packages to npm. What is the recommended way to do so ?

My problem:

- "npm install" seems to install packages in the "my_project/node_modules" folder, unlike bower which installs packages directly in my_project/www/lib/
- As explained for instance in the [installation guide of ionic.cloud](http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#installation) this requires an additional step to copy the newly installed npm package in the lib folder with the command:

  ```
  cp node_modules/@ionic/cloud/dist/bundle/ionic.cloud.min.js www/lib
  ```

However, when I update the package and run "npm update", this will update the node_modules folder, but not the lib folder. This is a problem as only the files from my lib folder are included in my index.html.

Running the cp-command after each npm update does not seem such an elegant solution. What is the recommended way to deal with this?

Comment: The way I am dealing with this currently is to create a symbolic link between my npm folder (node_modules/myPackage) and my www/lib folder. This is the less bad solution I found so far, but not yet optimal as we need to create a symlink for every new package and don't forget its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reverse this make the `.bowerrc` file create your packages inside the `node_modules` folder and use this path as default. Otherwise the `node_modules` is mandatory there is no way around creating it.
Even you can `npm i --prefix ./bower_components/ <package>` you still need to `cp` to folders up from `bower_components` folder